# Ubuntu 16 UFW not logging in /var/log/ufw.log neither another location

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

UFW is not logging on none location.

ufw configuration:

```
root@localhost:/var/log# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (full)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2022/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2022/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

root@localhost:/var/log#
```

rsyslog configuration:

```
root@localhost:/var/log# service rsyslog status
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-02-21 18:43:33 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
 Main PID: 283 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           └─283 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n

Feb 21 18:43:33 localhost systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Feb 21 18:43:33 localhost systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
root@localhost:/var/log#


root@localhost:/var/log# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& stop
```

there is no /var/log/ufw.log file, nor any mention to UFW in /var/log/syslog nor /var/log/kern.log (this last one there is not exists)

Why is UFW not logging?

Answer (score 5):

The solution was found on: https://superuser.com/questions/803996/no-kernel-messages-are-logged-to-kern-log

Edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and uncomment line:

```
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
```

Then, `sudo service rsyslog restart`

Comment: It is all over the web to edit `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf`, but this is the only answer that actually worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The actual issue here looks to be a permissions issue. The syslog user does
not have permission to create files in /var/log.

The log directory belongs to the syslog group however the
permissions for group are set to read/execute. As a result, rsyslogd is
unable to create new files in the directory but can update/write existing
files that have proper group permissions.

So fix permissions for whole folder, or just:

`touch /var/log/ufw.log && chown syslog:syslog /var/log/ufw.log`